# How to add arguments to a function called in panda's groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, parameter-passing

I'm trying to make a function that takes multiple arguments but it doesn't seem to work. The current code is:

```
def atomic(x):
    if np.in1d(x['concept:name'], 'W_Completeren aanvraag').sum() > 3:
        x['result'] = True
    else:
        x['result'] = False
    return x

df.groupby(['case:concept:name']).apply(atomic)
```

This code adds the column 'result' to df with the value True or False, depending on the outcome of the if statement.

I want to make the variables seen in the if statement, i.e. 'x['concept:name']' and 'W_Completeren aanvraag', argument. So the solution would like somewhat like this:

```
def atomic(x, key, check):
    if np.in1d(x[key], check).sum() > 3:
        x['result'] = True
    else:
        x['result'] = False
    return x

df.groupby(['case:concept:name']).apply(atomic('concept:name', 'W_Completeren aanvraag'))
```

However, the x variable is not callable when I script it like this, but I can't seem to figure out why it works at all without assigning the argument 'x' a value in the first place. It gives the error `TypeError: atomic() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) can receive the arguments for your function:

```
df.groupby(['case:concept:name']).apply(atomic, 'concept:name', 'W_Completeren aanvraag')
```

Comment: exactly what I need. Thank you very much!